# Stop masking placeholder in angular-ui-mask

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to stop masking placeholder in angular-ui-mask. I am using this for credit card field.

My code is something like this.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="accountNumber" ui-mask="9999 9999 9999 9999 999"  placeholder= "Enter Card Number" ui-mask-placeholder-char="space" />
</div>
```

When we click on the input field, the placeholder get unformatted.

Comment: You should be able to override the placeholder by editing addDefaultPlaceholder field.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working.
 addDefaultPlaceholder = "Enter card number"